# Do something after the last elemnt animation in an each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, each

I want do something after the last element animation in the each function.
I tried below code but it seems not working.

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
    var elems = $('.top-menu ul li'),
        i = 0;
    elems.each(function(i) {
        i += 1;
        $(this).delay(70*i).fadeIn(300);
        if(i == elems.length) {
          $('.bodyWrapper').addClass('noBodyScroll');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [`HTML` is missing..]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fairly close, just move it *into* the `fadeIn` callback, and don't manage `i` yourself; jQuery provides it as the first argument to your `each` callback already:

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
    var elems = $('.top-menu ul li');
    elems.each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(70*i).fadeIn(300, function() {       // ***
          if(i == elems.length - 1) {                      // *** note the - 1
            $('.bodyWrapper').addClass('noBodyScroll');
          }
        });
    });
});
```

That doesn't have the callbacks-in-a-loop problem because each call to the `each` callback gets its own `i` argument, which doesn't get updated.

Note that I left `i` alone before the first `70*i`. If it's important that the first element get delayed by those 70ms, you probably want to go ahead and increment `i` (which will only happen once):

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
    var elems = $('.top-menu ul li');
    elems.each(function(i) {
        ++i;                                            // ***
        $(this).delay(70*i).fadeIn(300, function() {
          if(i == elems.length) {                       // *** note the - 1 is gone
            $('.bodyWrapper').addClass('noBodyScroll');
          }
        });
    });
});
```